# At least one checkbox checked using jQuery siblings function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).on('click','.subject_add',function() {
      var $ele = $("input[type='checkbox']");
    var $btn = $(this);
    var $sameCheck = $btn.attr('id') && $ele.is(':checked') == $ele.attr('id').split('_')[2];
    alert($sameCheck);
    if(!$ele.is(':checked')) {
      Swal.fire('Oops','Please select the Add-on','error');
      return;
    }
    if($sameCheck) {
      Swal.fire('Oops','Please select the correct Add-on for the button','error');
      return;
    }
}
```

I am trying to make sure that every checkbox checked from the button which has the same ID. But possibly something is going wrong where it is not matching the same checkbox with same button.

my html:

```
<div align="left">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxid" name="subject_add" id="subject_add_3">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-info subject_add" id="3">Yes</a></p>

  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxid" name="subject_add" id="subject_add_4">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-info subject_add" id="4">Yes</a></p>

</div>
```

Comment: don't use multiple same id's, use then classes. Also posting your html would be helpful.

Comment: Show the full function... Not just a part. It is unclear when the function runs. -- Additionnaly, the comparision `$btn.attr('id') && $ele.is(':checked') == $ele.attr('id').split('_')[2]` does not make sense.

Comment: how to do comparison, the function is only that part

Comment: i added the full function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that closer to what you want?

When a click is made on a `.subject_add` link, there is an error message if the checkbox was not checked.

It uses [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to target the sibling checkboxes. No need for any `id` here. Just check if the checked count is the same as the checkbox count.

It would be easier to debug if you use a Swall `error` and a Swall `success`... With two `error` messages, sure it is getting confusing. ;)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.subject_add', function() {

  let boxCount = $(this).siblings("input[type='checkbox']").length
  let checkedCount = $(this).siblings("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length
  
  if (checkedCount) {
    Swal.fire('Okay!', 'The checkbox is checked', 'success');
  }
  else{
    Swal.fire('Oops', 'Check the checkbox first.', 'error');
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/10.14.0/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/10.14.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>


<div align="left">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxid" name="subject_add">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxid" name="subject_add">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxid" name="subject_add">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxid" name="subject_add">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxid" name="subject_add">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-info subject_add">Yes</a></p>

  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxid" name="subject_add">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxid" name="subject_add">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxid" name="subject_add">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-info subject_add">Yes</a></p>

</div>
```

Comment: it does not work, and prev will not work because it not only related to 1, it can have multiple checkboxes

Comment: it is always displaying an error, even if i select one checkbox , here is visual of what i am expecting

Comment: Ok. So you need at least one checked, but not all are needed. I edited.